# IMAPITable::GetContentsTable + GetRowCount retrieve inconsistent results

Tags: c++, email, outlook, mapi

I'm facing an awkward scenario where the following API calls return inconsistent results, or more precisely, i have to `.Release()` the `Contents table` couple of times before the `GetRowCount` yields anything significant

```
    if(FAILED(hr = spFolder->CreateFolder(FOLDER_SEARCH, &strOutLookSearchFolder[0],
        nullptr, nullptr, MAPI_UNICODE | OPEN_IF_EXISTS, &spSearchFolder)))
    {
        throw Exception("Failed creating search folder", hr);
    }

    if(FAILED(hr = spSearchFolder->SetSearchCriteria(spSRestriction_.get(),
        spEntryList.get(), RESTART_SEARCH | RECURSIVE_SEARCH | FOREGROUND_SEARCH)))
    {
        throw Exception("Failed setting search criteria", hr);
    }

ATL::CComPtr<IMAPITable> spContentsTable;
    if(FAILED(hr = spSearchFolder->GetContentsTable(0, &spContentsTable)))
    {
        LOG(ERR) << "Failed getting contents table";
        return;
    }

    ULONG ulMailCount = 0;
    if(SUCCEEDED(spContentsTable->GetRowCount(0, &ulMailCount)))
        spDataModelSubFolder->AddMessagesCount(ulMailCount);
```

**Edit:**

The above code crashes(DispatchMessage) weather or not i enter into SetSearchCriteria.

```
ATL::CComPtr<IMAPISession> spSession;
        if(FAILED(hr = pfnMAPILogonEx_(0, &profile.GetProfileName()[0], NULL,
                                MAPI_NEW_SESSION | MAPI_EXTENDED | /*MAPI_NO_MAIL |*/ MAPI_UNICODE, &spSession)))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                ....
                ....
                ....

               auto pfnHrAllocAdviseSink = (decltype(&::HrAllocAdviseSink))GetProcAddress(
                        (HMODULE)spMapiModule_.get(), "HrAllocAdviseSink@12"); 

                    ATL::CComPtr<IMAPIAdviseSink>   spAdviseSink;
                    bool                            bSearchCompleted =  false;
                    if(FAILED(hr = pfnHrAllocAdviseSink(SearchCompleteCallBack, 
                        &bSearchCompleted, &spAdviseSink)))
                    {
                        throw OutlookException("Failed allocating advise sink");
                    }

                    ULONG ulConnection = 0;
                    if(FAILED(hr = spMsgStore->Advise(
                        spPropSearchFolderEntryID->Value.bin.cb,
                        (LPENTRYID)spPropSearchFolderEntryID->Value.bin.lpb,
                        fnevSearchComplete,
                        spAdviseSink,
                        &ulConnection)))
                    {
                        throw OutlookException("Failed creating event sink");
                    }   

                    if(FAILED(hr = spSearchFolder->SetSearchCriteria(spSRestriction_.get(),
                        spEntryList.get(), RESTART_SEARCH | RECURSIVE_SEARCH)))
                    {
                        throw OutlookException("Failed setting search criteria", hr);
                    }

                    MSG msg = { 0 };
                    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0 ,0))
                    {
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
                        if (bSearchCompleted)
                            break;              
                    }   

    ....
    ....
    ....

    LONG STDAPICALLTYPE SearchCompleteCallBack(
        LPVOID          lpvContext,
        ULONG           cNotif,
        LPNOTIFICATION  lpNotif)
    {
        bool* pbSearchCompleted = (bool*)lpvContext;
        *pbSearchCompleted = true;
        return SUCCESS_SUCCESS;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Two different pointers to the contents table of the same folder?

Comment: Looks like it was a mistake due to a continues debugging attempt which didn't end well, I'v just realized i need to use AdviseSink and wait for the SetSearchCriteria to complete

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko: Is it possible to create IMAPIAdviseSink without executing HrAllocAdviseSink? Im using olmapi32.dll and cant rely on mapi32.dll

Comment: You are nto supposed to load olmapi32.dlll - load msmapi32.dll. It implements HrAllocAdviseSink as well as all other MAPI functions. And yes, you don't have to use HrAllocAdviseSink - I never use that function, but rather create my own COM object that implements the IMAPIAdviseSink interface.

Comment: One last thing, my DispatchMessage crashes regardless to what im doing, waiting or no waiting or the SetSearchCriteria. im editing my original post

Comment: Are you just spinning gin a loop waiting for the search to complete? Don't, use a callback, or check the status periodically later. If you want the search to be synchronous, do nto use a search folder.

Comment: Infact i do use a callback(see EDIT), i have a GetMessage loop until the callback is executed and signs the bool  variable

Comment: Don't do that - firstly, you have sleep() on the main thread, and secondly that is not how search folders are supposed to be used...

Comment: Can you refer me to a working example? mine is taken directly from MSDN (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260322) so i dont really understand what the difference is

Comment: Are you running your code in a command line app? Or GUI?

Comment: non console command line